# How do people manage ini files in production systems?

Tags: migration, installation, config, inno-setup, ini

We are using the Innosetup installer to install our binaries and  INI Files onto a system.
On an upgrade, we simply remove existing binaries and install new ones.
However it is a bit different with INI files, becuase the user can edits ini file values and we want to preserve that change. Before we install an updated ini file, we copy the existing ini files with _copy appended to the name, remove the original ini files, install new ini files with defaults, then read the _copy ini files back in and restore values using (Section,key).

---This system works fine, until we decide to rename keys or change section names. Then we have to have scripts that update the ini files post install.

The problem I am seeing in the long run with my current strategy is if a user wants to update from 1.0.1 to 1.0.9, how do we handle that?
Force them to run each installer from 1.0.1 to 1.0.9?
Build a migration tool?   Is there a strategy that someone is currently using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies to databases as well as any structured data that is versioned.
You need to decide if you support migration, and if you do then you create a migration script or utility that goes between each version. And by version I mean each version that changes the schema of the data for a particular user data resource. Keep each migration separate and then migrate one at a time. so if you have to migrate across 4 versions then migrate from 1->2 2->3 3->4. Isolate code that is just around for migration into a migration library. At some point you have to decide which versions you support for migration. If you decide to stop supporting a migration path then they might need to install an older version first. Basically, I'd provide migration, but be reasonable for what you support.

If possible, leave a backup of the original user data and leave it up to the user to delete it. This way manual rollback or upgrade would still be possible.

All of this is kind of assuming a more enterprise product with a sales engineer or at least a more direct relationship with the customer as that's the only experience I have. If your product is for mass consumption, then it might be smarter to support legacy ini and leave the user data alone. I would expect structured data like YAML/JSON or a database to have schema updates that need to be migrated, but something as simple as an INI file should be easy to support legacy versions as it's just key/value.

Answer (score 0):

The user INI file is user's only, never change it.

- Have the default values hard-coded in the application or in a separate defaults INI file.
- Make the application fallback to legacy key names or sections names, if the latest names are not found.

Comment: I think we don't want to make changes in our code to handle legacy files, rather make the edits to INIs during version upgrades.

Comment: @lukesignh This reminds me, you should leave a backup of the previous version with a timestamp and .bak extension so that if there are any complications with migration at least they have an option of manual rollback or upgrade